# Usb bootdisk files help

Tags: usb, files

I had files on a usb ubuntu boot disk that I would like to retrieve. I copied the files to a rar file on my hard drive. I would like to know if there is anyway I can access the files that were in the boot drive desktop, as I do not have the usb drive any more. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "Backed them up"? How?

Comment: I coped them all to a rar file sorry mom typed this up for me even though I said I'd do it later.

Comment: Do you have a persistent Ubuntu live USB which you booted from, and saved the .rar file somewhere in the live file system's storage?

Comment: I did have persistent and I saved the rar to my hard drive so I can still get to it the usb drive broke how ever I'm going to look in to fixing it later but no long has the files on it I backed up the boot disk not the files I want. what I'm asking is there a way to get those files or where they are.

Comment: I'm not sure that your USB drive is broken. What often happens in cases like yours is that the drive was not safely removed and the physical drive can be restored to a useful condition by reformatting it using Gparted. However since you've got a **data recovery** issue for files that are still on that drive, you should try to recover your files before you attempt to reformat the drive.

Comment: No it is it's physically broken. If I cant fix it I will try to use isp to get the files off i need to.

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to find the .rar file(s). You can use the operating system's tool for searching the filesystem to do this. You will be able to find the file(s), because they are on the same filesystem as your fully working operating system.

Then, use a tool such as [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [peazip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/) to decompress any files you need.

I have no way of knowing where you could have saved the rar file(s) because I am not you. Best of luck with finding your data!

Comment: I don't know how that woudl help and I know where the rar file is

Comment: You should extract the contents of the .rar file and look for the files you need amongst the extracted files.

Comment: The files I'm talking about are the ones that made up the boot drive.

Comment: If you erased the USB disk without first backing up the files, they are probably unrecoverable.